# simple functions

Tags: measure-theory

let  $m_f(A)=\int_{A} f dm$
suppose that f is a simple function that is $f= \sum c_{i} 1_{A_{i}}$
describe f.
this is part of a problem where i had to prove that $m_f(A)$ is a measure and i had also to describe it when f= the characteristic function.
the only issue i have in the case of simple functions is that when it takes negative values how do i integrate.
i know that for non negative simple functions $\int_{A}\sum c_{i} 1_{A_{i}}= \sum c_{i} m(A_{i})$. however i am not sure  if this fact still holds when the function takes negative values .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m_f$ will only be a measure for non-negative functions $f$ (Else, if $c_i = -t$, $t>0$ then $m_f(A_i) = -t\ m(A_i)<0$).
As to your question, the integral in measure theory is defined this way: Take $f = f_+ - f_-$ where $f_+ = \max(f,0)$ and $f_- = \max(-f, 0)$ then
$$\int_A f d\mu := \int_Af_+ d\mu - \int_A f_- d\mu$$

---

In your special case if
$$f = \sum_{i=1}^N c_i 1_{A_i}$$
where $\mu(A_i) < \infty \quad \forall i$ and $I_+ := \{i : c_i > 0\}$, $I_- := \{i : c_i < 0\}$ and thus
$$f_+ = \sum_{i\in I_+} c_i 1_{A_i}, \qquad f_- = \sum_{i\in I_-} -c_i 1_{A_i}$$
And by definition
$$\int f d\mu = \int \sum_{i\in I_+} c_i 1_{A_i} d\mu - \int \sum_{i\in I_-} -c_i 1_{A_i} d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^N c_i \int 1_{A_i} d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^N c_i \mu(A_i)$$

Comment: i think $\int_A f d\mu := \int_Af_+ d\mu - \int_A f_- d\mu $ this holds only if  u know that f is integrable

Comment: All simple functions are integrable by definition :)

Comment: lebesgue integrable ? what about a constant function on a set with measure infinity

Comment: Then the integral doesn't exist, but the funciton is still integrable on any set with finite measure or on any finite measure-space.

Comment: Also, my definition of a simple function included $\mu(A_i) < \infty \quad \forall i$, which exludes your example.

Comment: so your proof holds only in finite measure spaces, correct?

Comment: @toufik_kh.17 See above: if simple functions are required to be linear combinations of characteristic functions of sets of finite measure, it holds for all. Also, this is no "proof"; it is simply the definition of the integral for any function by splitting into positive and negative parts.

Comment: in my book it states that $\mu(A_i \cap X)$ can be + infinity.

Comment: @toufik_kh.17 This is only a matter of convention. In this case, the integal of such a function with $c_i \neq 0$ is undefined.

Comment: thank for the clarification that was helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can only ensure that $m$ is a measure if $f$ is a non-negative measurable function. Otherwise suppose as in your case, if you take a simple function, $f=\sum c_i1_{A_i}$ and $c_n$ is negative for some $n$, then $m(A_n)<0$, which implies $m$ is not a measure.

However, for a measurable function $f$, $m(A)=\int_A fd\mu$ defines a set function that is countably additive and satisfies $m(\emptyset)=0$.

Comment: \emptyset is the way to go ;-)

Comment: thank you this makes a sense. i guess the problem i am working on is either tricky or missing details.

Comment: @toufik_kh.17 refer to my answer for this.